# Drawing circuit diagrams (with logic gates) in LaTeX

Tags: graphics, diagrams, circuitikz, logic

I'm having some difficult drawing circuit diagrams with logic gates in LaTeX. I've tried with `circuitikz` and `pst-circ`.

```
\begin{pspicture}(-1,-1)(5,3)
\logicand[ninputs=2,invertinputa=true, invertinputb=true](0,0){Name}
\end{pspicture}
```

gives

```
Error: ! Undefined control sequence.
<recently read> \c@lor@to@ps 

l.75 ...inputa=true, invertinputb=true](0,0){Name}

?
```

And

```
\begin{circuitikz} \draw
(0,2) node[and port] (myand1) {}
(0,0) node[and port] (myand2) {}
(2,1) node[xnor port] (myxnor) {};
(myand1.out) | (myxnor.in 1)
(myand2.out) | (myxnor.in 2)
\end{circuitikz}
```

produces no error, but also no lines appear between logic gates.

Please help me generate logic diagrams from LaTeX code. (I need AND, OR, NOT, NOR and NAND gates.)

Comment: You're never going to get `pst-circ` to work with PDFLaTeX. Run `texdoc pstricks` and read the section on PDFTeX workarounds.

Comment: Please include complete [minimal working examples (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) (with preambles) so that the code can be simply copy&pasted to diagnose problems.

Comment: Run your example with `xelatex` instead of `pdflatex`

Comment: How can I draw a negative-and gate?
Thanks.

Comment: @AlbertO This space is reserved strictly for answers however you can ask a new question with a minimum working example demonstrating your effort. It doesn't need to be directly showing possible solution but people can copy/paste your example and work on it without coming up a code from scratch.

Comment: @AlbertO Just use the keyword "nand" instead of the other keywords (e.g.: nor, xor) in the examples shown in the other answers.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

For the `circuitikz` approach: You need to tell TikZ what to do with `(myand1.out)`, `(myxnor.in 1)`, and so on. At the moment, you just mention the nodes, but don't tell TikZ to actually connect them, because you ended the previous `\draw` command already with the `;`. Also, to connect nodes with straight lines, you need to use `--`, not `|`.

Here's your example in a full MWE.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{circuitikz}
\begin{document}

\begin{circuitikz} \draw
(0,2) node[and port] (myand1) {}
(0,0) node[and port] (myand2) {}
(2,1) node[xnor port] (myxnor) {}
(myand1.out) -- (myxnor.in 1)
(myand2.out) -- (myxnor.in 2);
\end{circuitikz}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks (voted up). How do I show the progression of variables? - So lets say I have an x,y and z`, how would I show the progressing to an f(x,y,z`), as it goes through the circuit?

Comment: That should probably be asked as a separate question.

Comment: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/32939/

Answer (score 24):

I've never used `circuitikz` but `shapes.gates.logic` tikzlibrary.  You have AND, NOT, NOR and all logic gates, place them as regular tikz nodes and draw connections. That's all. Here you have an example:

```
\documentclass[border=3mm]{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,shapes.gates.logic.US,shapes.gates.logic.IEC,calc}
\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\tikzstyle{branch}=[fill,shape=circle,minimum size=3pt,inner sep=0pt]
\begin{tikzpicture}[label distance=2mm]

    \node (x3) at (0,0) {$x_3$};
    \node (x2) at (1,0) {$x_2$};
    \node (x1) at (2,0) {$x_1$};
    \node (x0) at (3,0) {$x_0$};

    \node[not gate US, draw, rotate=-90] at ($(x2)+(0.5,-1)$) (Not2) {};
    \node[not gate US, draw, rotate=-90] at ($(x1)+(0.5,-1)$) (Not1) {};
    \node[not gate US, draw, rotate=-90] at ($(x0)+(0.5,-1)$) (Not0) {};

    \node[or gate US, draw, logic gate inputs=nnn] at ($(x0)+(2,-2)$) (Or1) {};
    \node[or gate US, draw, logic gate inputs=nnnn] at ($(Or1)+(0,-1)$) (Or2) {};
    \node[or gate US, draw, logic gate inputs=nnn] at ($(Or2)+(0,-1)$) (Or3) {};
    \node[xor gate US, draw, logic gate inputs=nn] at ($(Or3)+(0,-1)$) (Xor1) {};
    \node[and gate US, draw, logic gate inputs=nn, anchor=input 1] at ($(Or3.output)+(1,0)$) (And1) {};
    \node[nor gate US, draw, logic gate inputs=nn, anchor=input 1] at ($(Or2.output -| And1.output)+(1,0)$) (Nor1) {};
    \node[and gate US, draw, logic gate inputs=nn, anchor=input 1] at ($(Or1.output -| Nor1.output)+(1,0)$) (And2) {};

    \foreach \i in {2,1,0}
    {
        \path (x\i) -- coordinate (punt\i) (x\i |- Not\i.input);
        \draw (punt\i) node[branch] {} -| (Not\i.input);
    }
    \draw (x3) |- (Or2.input 1);
    \draw (x3 |- Or1.input 1) node[branch] {} -- (Or1.input 1);
    \draw (x2) |- (Xor1.input 1);
    \draw (x2 |- Or3.input 1) node[branch] {} -- (Or3.input 1);
    \draw (Not2.output) |- (Or2.input 2);
    \draw (x1) |- (Or3.input 2);
    \draw (x1 |- Or1.input 2) node[branch] {} -- (Or1.input 2);
    \draw (Not1.output) |- (Xor1.input 2);
    \draw (Not1.output |- Or2.input 3) node[branch] {} -- (Or2.input 3);
    \draw (x0) |- (Or2.input 4);
    \draw (Not0.output) |- (Or3.input 3);
    \draw (Not0.output |- Or1.input 3) node[branch] {} -- (Or1.input 3);
    \draw (Or3.output) -- (And1.input 1);
    \draw (Xor1.output) -- ([xshift=0.5cm]Xor1.output) |- (And1.input 2);
    \draw (Or2.output) -- (Nor1.input 1);
    \draw (And1.output) -- ([xshift=0.5cm]And1.output) |- (Nor1.input 2);
    \draw (Or1.output) -- (And2.input 1);
    \draw (Nor1.output) -- ([xshift=0.5cm]Nor1.output) |- (And2.input 2);
    \draw (And2.output) -- ([xshift=0.5cm]And2.output) node[above] {$f_1$};

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: That looks quite nice, and is the kind of thing I'm looking for. Is there anyway to make the code more concise? - I am typing up lectures in realtime, so need to keep up...

Comment: @AT: I don't know how to do it more concise. I just can think in using some style like `and2/.style={and gate US, draw, logic gate inputs=nn}` and later use `\node[and2]`, but in any case you need to place gates and draw their connections between outputs and particular inputs. `matrix` and, maybe, `chain` libraries can help a little bit.

Comment: Mmm... maybe I should try something in Python with graphviz and plasTeX... basically I want to just use variables and gates naturally. i.e.:  x-[and1]-[or1]-f1, y-[and2]-[or1](-f1)|(-[and1]), z-[f1]

Answer (score 5):

I'm not entirely sure what you're after; here is an example taken directly from the documentation, which you can find by running

```
texdoc pst-circ
```

When using `PSTricks` if you use

```
latex myfile.tex
dvips myfile.dvi
ps2pdf myfile.ps
```

then the following file will work

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pst-circ}

\begin{document}

\begin{pspicture}(-4,0)(5,7)
\psset{logicWidth=1, logicHeight=2, dotsize=0.15}
\logic[logicWireLength=0](-2,0){A0}
\logic[logicWireLength=0](-2,5){A1}
\ncbar[angleA=-180,angleB=-180,arm=0.5]{A11}{A02}
\psline[dotsize=0.15]{-*}(-3.5,3.5)(-2.5,3.5)
\uput[180](-3.5,3.5){$T$}
\psline(-3.5,0.5)(A01)\uput[180](-3.5,0.5){$S$}
\psline(-3.5,6.5)(A12)\uput[180](-3.5,6.5){$R$}
\psset{logicType=nor, logicLabelstyle=\normalsize}
\logic(1,0.5){nor1}
\logic(1,4.5){nor2}
\psline(nor2Q)(4,0|nor2Q)
\uput[0](4,0|nor2Q){$Q$}
\psline(nor1Q)(4,0|nor1Q)
\uput[0](4,0|nor1Q){$\overline{Q}$}
\psline{*-}(3,0|nor2Q)(3,4)(1,4)(0,3)(0,0|nor12)(nor12)
\psline{*-}(3,0|nor1Q)(3,3)(1,3)(0,4)(0,0|nor21)(nor21)
\psline(A0Q)(nor11)
\psline(A1Q)(nor22)
\end{pspicture}

\end{document}
```

If you would prefer to use `pdflatex` then your preamble should look like

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[pdf]{pstricks}
\usepackage{pst-circ}

\begin{document}
...
```

and then you can run

```
pdflatex -shell-escape myfile.tex
```

[image]

Comment: looks horrible, why square ...

Answer (score 0):

Try this [generator](https://latex-editor.pages.dev/graph/) will work for simple cases and it uses Tikz

for your case latex code will be like this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric, arrows}

\begin{document}

\usetikzlibrary {circuits.logic.US}
\begin{tikzpicture}[circuit logic US]
\matrix[column sep=4mm, row sep=4mm] {
\node [and gate ] (f5fbb9ac-ba33-4ab5-96bc-d0af34cee8a1) {}; & & \\ 
& & \node [xnor gate ] (a6b7442d-0f66-4798-9db4-25a81365166e) {}; \\ 
\node [and gate ] (ca150480-f272-4220-9df1-14d5893b1ae2) {}; & & \\ 
};

\draw (f5fbb9ac-ba33-4ab5-96bc-d0af34cee8a1.output) -- ++(right:2mm) |- (a6b7442d-0f66-4798-9db4-25a81365166e.input 1);
\draw (ca150480-f272-4220-9df1-14d5893b1ae2.output) -- ++(right:2mm) |- (a6b7442d-0f66-4798-9db4-25a81365166e.input 2);


\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```