# Using circuitikz to generate logic circuit diagrams?

Tags: tikz-pgf, diagrams, circuitikz, logic

How can I use `circuitikz` (or similar library for small code) to generate logic circuit diagrams with full variable life.

```
x ---[and1]--- z

y ---[and1]--- z
```

So `f(x,y)=z`

An image of the kind of thing I'd like to generate:

[image: http://adamwsonu.files.wordpress.com/2010/03/quizcircuit.png]

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) It's not necessary to sign your questions (as there is already a box with your username below it) or to begin them with a greeting.

Comment: How is this question different from: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/32839/drawing-circuit-diagrams-with-logic-gates-in-latex?

Comment: @Jake: Ah, I see.

Comment: Just to clarify: You only want to label the inputs/outputs and generate a blank logic table, not automatically calculate the output, right?

Comment: Right. Although it would be interesting to see the other...

Comment: @Kottwitz thanks for closing the exact question I want to ask.