# How to add ports to logic gates?

Tags: circuitikz, draw

I am trying to draw the following image in LaTeX. But by so far I was able to draw the square and or gate. Can some help to draw this? Thanks.

[image: port]

Comment: Can you add your code? As minimal working example?(https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that)

Answer (score 1):

A quick google search will lead you to the following very helpful pages:

[Drawing circuit diagrams (with logic gates) in LaTeX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/32839/drawing-circuit-diagrams-with-logic-gates-in-latex)

https://notgnoshi.github.io/drawing-logic-gates-with-tikz/

http://www.texample.net/tikz/examples/logic-circuits-library/