# Logic circuit dot drawing

Tags: diagrams

I have a question about drawing logic circuits. How to draw these dots and two lines from the dot to nand logic gate?

[image]

I just need the part of code where you draw simple line dot line with easy solution to connect between logic gates not the whole code generating this image.

```
\draw (A |- (nand.input 1) %dot% -- (nand.input1);
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX. Instead of posting a link to I guess an image it would be nice if you could include it directly using the "image" button. Also it would be nice if you could provide some code with what you have achieved so far, so not *all* the work to create a document is with us, the helpers. Thank you.

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/370259/need-help-with-a-circuit-diagram/370726#370726