# How to draw a Boolean circuit using circuitikz

Tags: tikz-pgf

How to draw circuit like the following using circuitikz [image]. Also, I would like to know how to add dashed boxes in some part of the circuit

Comment: Welcome to TexSE. In order to help you, we need to see what you've already tried in a "My working example" with a minimum code of yours. In other words, help us, help you :) As a start, check maybe https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/32839/drawing-circuit-diagrams-with-logic-gates-in-latex or https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/32839/drawing-circuit-diagrams-with-logic-gates-in-latex I found them through on Google with  site:tex.stackexchange.com <Boolean circuit circuitikz> and checked images.

Comment: Which boxes do you want to dash, there are no dashed boxes in your circuit?

Comment: I want to add a dashed box for example for the AND and the XOR gates together, I mean a big box contain both of them

Comment: @Nehad to do that, use my code from the answer and add `\node[fit=(xor)(and), draw, dashed] {};` at the end.

Comment: @TobiBS It does not work in my overleaf file the same as multiwire :(. No another way to do so?.

Comment: @Nehad sorry I forgot to mention this requires a `\usetikzlibrary{fit}` in the preamble.

Comment: @TobiBS for multiwire which library I have to use?

Comment: @Nehad, why are you trying to edit my answer? If you have different requirements, please modify your question, or ask an additional question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you want to start playing around with this and ask some more specific questions?

[image]

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}

\usepackage{circuitikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{circuitikz}
    \draw
    (1,0) node[twoportshape, t=S'] (ss) {}
    (2,1.5) node[twoportshape, t=S] (s) {}
    (3,0) node[twoportshape, t=G] (g) {}
    (4,1.5) node[twoportshape, t=G] (gg) {}
    (3,3) node[twoportshape, t=R] (r) {}
    (8,2.25) node[and port] (and) {}
    (12,0.75) node[xor port] (xor) {}
    (and.out) to[multiwire=$\rho$] ++ (1,0) -| (xor.in 1)
    (g.right) to[multiwire=$\rho$] ++ (1,0) -| (xor.in 2)
    (r.right) to[multiwire=$\rho$] ++ (1,0) -| (and.in 1)
    (gg.right) to[multiwire=$\rho$] ++ (1,0) -| (and.in 2)
    (s.right) to[multiwire=$n$] ++ (1,0) -- (gg.left)
    (ss.right) to[multiwire=$n$] ++ (1,0) -- (g.left)
    (0,3)node[left]{b} -- (r.left)
    (0,1.5)node[left]{0} -- (s.left)
    (0,0)node[left]{0} -- (ss.left)
    (xor.out) to[multiwire=$\rho$] ++ (1,0)node[right]{c};
\end{circuitikz}
    
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you very much

Comment: multiwire does not work What can I do?. My tex file doesn't recognize the multiwire command. also if you can teach me how ho add text in top of the wire?

Comment: @NehadMabrouk, check if you have installed the last version of the `circuitikz` package (version 1.1.2 (2020/05/17) ). For labels of `multiwire` see package documentation,  subsection *3.12 Multiple wires (buses)*, page 58--59.

Comment: @Zarko I am using an online tex editor (overleaf).

Comment: @NehadMabrouk, than you need to ask Overleaf support for help. Unfortunately, they do not upgrade their LaTeX installation enough frequently :-(.