Problem with delimiter using the chemfig package
This is my first post here, so please excuse me if I do anything wrong.
I have a problem using the \chemleft and \chemright commands. I use LuaLaTeX to compile. Whenever I try to compile the MWE given below, the delimiters look different from what I would expect.
\documentclass[11pt]{scrarticle}

\usepackage[no-math]{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Arial}
\usepackage[Arial]{mathfont}

\usepackage{chemfig}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\begin{document}
\chemleft[\chemfig{H-[1]O-[7]H}\chemright]

\qty{1}{\mole}
\end{document}

This is the result:

I am aware that this is a problem caused by the use of Arial as a font, but I would be very grateful for any advices to prevent this from happening while still using Arial as the main font.
I also want to use the siunitx-package in most of my documents, so I use the mathfont-package in order to achieve Arial as a font when using e.g. \qty{}{}.
I would be very grateful for any ideas or solutions for my problem, thanks in advance!
Edit:
My desired output for the delimiter would look like this:

This was achieved by leaving out the mathfont package:
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{scrarticle}


\usepackage[]{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Arial}
% \usepackage[Arial]{mathfont}

\usepackage{chemfig}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\begin{document}
\chemleft[\chemfig{H-[1]O-[7]H}\chemright]

\qty{1}{\mole}
\end{document}

But of course this is not my desired output for the siunitx package, since it then does not use Arial as font any more.

So, you do not want the shown result. But what result do you want?

Three suggestions: 1) Don't change the font, at least not for now. TeX was carefully designed together with certain fonts. Don't expect, packages by and large adjusted to all possible fonts available worldwide. 2) If needed try switching to the built-in sans serif family, \sffamily. But check with chemfigs manual. 3) You can often reduce trouble if you follow a two-files approach, i,e, not useing said KOMA-class. See here for an example: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/701681/how-to-draw-pi-controller-block-diagram/701698#701698 , where the including document can be KOMA

@Stephen I edited my post to show my desired result. Thank you.

@MS-SPO Thank you for your suggestions, I will look into it!

Fine. Feel free to answer to yourself, once you found a viable solution. // I forgot to mention that you can run standalone with pdflatex, unless chemfig likes a different dialect.

One way is to define only the delimiters to be in a different font that has nicer looking delimiters. The mathfont package has command for this, which is \mathfont[delimiters]{Name Of Font}. However, if you have already set the font with \usepackage[Name Of Different Font]{mathfont} then it doesn't work and you get a warning that the font for the delimiters was already set. You can force a redefinition by setting the corresponding boolean, called \M@delimiters, to false before using \mathfont.
MWE, using Nimbus Sans L (an Arial clone) as main and math font and STIXSizeOneSym as delimiter font:
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{scrarticle}
\usepackage[no-math]{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Nimbus Sans L}
\usepackage[Nimbus Sans L]{mathfont}
\makeatletter
\M@delimitersfalse
\makeatother
\mathfont[delimiters]{STIXSizeOneSym}
\usepackage{chemfig}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\begin{document}
\chemleft[\chemfig{H-[1]O-[7]H}\chemright]

\qty{1}{\mole}

\end{document}

Result:


Note that the STIX delimiter is a bit too high, maybe another font will result in a better fit.

Thank you very much! I fiddled around with this idea as well, but I got stuck at the point where the delimiters are already defined! This is awesome, thanks a lot!
