what packages do i need to use in order for LyX to compile and render images made with mathcha.io?
I'm using LyX and I recently found out that mathcha.io lets you convert images and plots, which you can easily create, to tikz code.
I tried using it but when compiling it only shows certain things; for example, it renders some logic gate circuits, but doesn't load plots (2D, 3D, etc...), (I'll add that to get to this in mathcha.io you first need to enter the diagram/drawing environment by typing "\drawing") so I believe I must be missing some packages, here's an example of the code generated by mathcha.io that's supposed to work inside a TeX code environment in LyX but doesn't render:
\tikzset{every picture/.style={line width=0.75pt}} %set default line width to 0.75pt        
\begin{tikzpicture}[x=0.75pt,y=0.75pt,yscale=-1,xscale=1] %uncomment if require: 
\path (0,300); %set diagram left start at 0, and has height of 300
\end{tikzpicture} 

and here is an example of code that does render properly (though I don't know of an easy way to position it in the exact place like in the LyX document):
\tikzset{every picture/.style={line width=0.75pt}} %set default line width to 0.75pt        
\begin{tikzpicture}[x=0.75pt,y=0.75pt,yscale=-1,xscale=1] %uncomment if require: \path (0,300); %set diagram left start at 0, and has height of 300
%Shape: Axis 2D [id:dp7108345265772975]  
\draw  (50,162) -- (150,162)(60,72) -- (60,172) (143,157) -- (150,162) -- (143,167) (55,79) -- (60,72) -- (65,79)  ; 
%Shape: Parabola [id:dp7278250032221381]  
\draw   (25,122) .. controls (48.33,175.33) and (71.67,175.33) .. (95,122) ; 
%Shape: Wave [id:dp767344400003916]  
\draw   (164.99,135.62) .. controls (161.1,125.31) and (157.38,115.48) .. (152.85,115.4) .. controls (148.33,115.32) and (144.26,125.01) .. (140,135.18) .. controls (135.74,145.35) and (131.67,155.03) .. (127.14,154.95) .. controls (122.62,154.87) and (118.9,145.05) .. (115,134.73) .. controls (111.11,124.42) and (107.38,114.59) .. (102.86,114.51) .. controls (100.2,114.47) and (97.69,117.8) .. (95.21,122.62) ;
\end{tikzpicture} 

I assume that the plots in mathcha.io are generated using some way that can only be accessed through the website itself, so when you try to copy the Tikz code it loses the info of whatever was supposed to be inside.

In general, the packages you need are tikz and sometimes pgfplots. The first code you show, though, is just a (non stroked) point, so it renders  to nothing.

You need to have \usepackage{tikz} one way or the other in the preamble.
First, let's have a look at LaTeX code. If I copy your two codes like this:
\documentclass[10pt,border=3mm,tikz]{standalone}

\begin{document}

\tikzset{every picture/.style={line width=0.75pt}} %set default line width to 0.75pt        
\begin{tikzpicture}[x=0.75pt,y=0.75pt,yscale=-1,xscale=1] %uncomment if require: 
\path (0,300); %set diagram left start at 0, and has height of 300
\end{tikzpicture} 

\tikzset{every picture/.style={line width=0.75pt}} %set default line width to 0.75pt        
\begin{tikzpicture}[x=0.75pt,y=0.75pt,yscale=-1,xscale=1] %uncomment if require: \path (0,300); %set diagram left start at 0, and has height of 300
%Shape: Axis 2D [id:dp7108345265772975]  
\draw  (50,162) -- (150,162)(60,72) -- (60,172) (143,157) -- (150,162) -- (143,167) (55,79) -- (60,72) -- (65,79)  ; 
%Shape: Parabola [id:dp7278250032221381]  
\draw   (25,122) .. controls (48.33,175.33) and (71.67,175.33) .. (95,122) ; 
%Shape: Wave [id:dp767344400003916]  
\draw   (164.99,135.62) .. controls (161.1,125.31) and (157.38,115.48) .. (152.85,115.4) .. controls (148.33,115.32) and (144.26,125.01) .. (140,135.18) .. controls (135.74,145.35) and (131.67,155.03) .. (127.14,154.95) .. controls (122.62,154.87) and (118.9,145.05) .. (115,134.73) .. controls (111.11,124.42) and (107.38,114.59) .. (102.86,114.51) .. controls (100.2,114.47) and (97.69,117.8) .. (95.21,122.62) ;
\end{tikzpicture} 

\end{document}

it renders:

the standalone class puts one "page" per tikzpicture
the first one basically contains ... a point \path (0,300);
while the second looks fine enough


LyX in contrast seems to be a bit more stubborn with this code:

Documents / Settings / Preamble: add  \usepackage{tikz} there
copying the second code into the red box didn't render the Preview correctly
turned out I had to enter returns to "free" the \draw statements manually from their having been commented out (??? LyX ...)

Unfortunately I can't compile, but here for reference:

Lyx-file: copy into an ASCII editor, save it, load it, should compile in your place:
#LyX 2.3 created this file. For more info see http://www.lyx.org/
\lyxformat 544
\begin_document
\begin_header
\save_transient_properties true
\origin unavailable
\textclass article
\begin_preamble
\usepackage{tikz}
\end_preamble
\use_default_options true
\maintain_unincluded_children false
\language english
\language_package default
\inputencoding auto
\fontencoding global
\font_roman "default" "default"
\font_sans "default" "default"
\font_typewriter "default" "default"
\font_math "auto" "auto"
\font_default_family default
\use_non_tex_fonts false
\font_sc false
\font_osf false
\font_sf_scale 100 100
\font_tt_scale 100 100
\use_microtype false
\use_dash_ligatures true
\graphics default
\default_output_format default
\output_sync 0
\bibtex_command default
\index_command default
\paperfontsize default
\spacing single
\use_hyperref false
\papersize default
\use_geometry false
\use_package amsmath 1
\use_package amssymb 1
\use_package cancel 1
\use_package esint 1
\use_package mathdots 1
\use_package mathtools 1
\use_package mhchem 1
\use_package stackrel 1
\use_package stmaryrd 1
\use_package undertilde 1
\cite_engine basic
\cite_engine_type default
\biblio_style plain
\use_bibtopic false
\use_indices false
\paperorientation portrait
\suppress_date false
\justification true
\use_refstyle 1
\use_minted 0
\index Index
\shortcut idx
\color #008000
\end_index
\secnumdepth 3
\tocdepth 3
\paragraph_separation indent
\paragraph_indentation default
\is_math_indent 0
\math_numbering_side default
\quotes_style english
\dynamic_quotes 0
\papercolumns 1
\papersides 1
\paperpagestyle default
\tracking_changes false
\output_changes false
\html_math_output 0
\html_css_as_file 0
\html_be_strict false
\end_header

\begin_body

\begin_layout Standard
\begin_inset ERT
status open

\begin_layout Plain Layout


\backslash
tikzset{every picture/.style={line width=0.75pt}} %set default line width
 to 0.75pt         
\end_layout

\end_inset


\end_layout

\begin_layout Standard
\begin_inset ERT
status open

\begin_layout Plain Layout


\backslash
begin{tikzpicture}[x=0.75pt,y=0.75pt,yscale=-1,xscale=1] %uncomment if require:
 
\backslash
path (0,300); %set diagram left start at 0, and has height of 300 %Shape:
 Axis 2D [id:dp7108345265772975]   
\end_layout

\begin_layout Plain Layout

\end_layout

\begin_layout Plain Layout


\backslash
draw  (50,162) -- (150,162)(60,72) -- (60,172) (143,157) -- (150,162) --
 (143,167) (55,79) -- (60,72) -- (65,79)  ;  %Shape: Parabola [id:dp727825003222
1381]   
\end_layout

\begin_layout Plain Layout

\end_layout

\begin_layout Plain Layout


\backslash
draw   (25,122) ..
 controls (48.33,175.33) and (71.67,175.33) ..
 (95,122) ;  %Shape: Wave [id:dp767344400003916]   
\backslash
draw   (164.99,135.62) ..
 controls (161.1,125.31) and (157.38,115.48) ..
 (152.85,115.4) ..
 controls (148.33,115.32) and (144.26,125.01) ..
 (140,135.18) ..
 controls (135.74,145.35) and (131.67,155.03) ..
 (127.14,154.95) ..
 controls (122.62,154.87) and (118.9,145.05) ..
 (115,134.73) ..
 controls (111.11,124.42) and (107.38,114.59) ..
 (102.86,114.51) ..
 controls (100.2,114.47) and (97.69,117.8) ..
 (95.21,122.62) ; 
\end_layout

\begin_layout Plain Layout


\backslash
end{tikzpicture} 
\end_layout

\end_inset


\end_layout

\end_body
\end_document


thank you very much, as it stands it looks like too much work, when I stumbled upon mathcha I thought it could be an easy way to generate plots and all, but as you explained it takes way more time than what's convenient, I'll look around for some other way to generate plots or at the end just learn tikz for good haha

Ok. Here's an alternative: a) print each drawing as .pdf (!) via matcha.io, b) load it, as described here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/701698/245790
