Problem in block diagram
I have to make schematic flowchart of a fever model. here's what i want to create

Here's what i have tried so far
    \documentclass{article}
    \usepackage{tikz}
    \usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric, arrows, calc}

    \begin{document}

    \begin{tikzpicture}
    % Nodes
    \node[draw, regular polygon, regular polygon sides=6, minimum size=1cm] (Sr) at (0,4) {$S_{r}$};
   \node[draw, regular polygon, regular polygon sides=6, minimum size=1cm] (Ir) at (4,4) {$I_{r}$};
   \node[draw, regular polygon, regular polygon sides=6, minimum size=1cm] (Sh) at (0,2) {$S_{h}$};
   \node[draw, regular polygon, regular polygon sides=6, minimum size=1cm] (Eh) at (2,2) {$E_{h}$};
   \node[draw, regular polygon, regular polygon sides=6, minimum size=1cm] (Ih) at (4,2) {$I_{h}$};
   \node[draw, regular polygon, regular polygon sides=6, minimum size=1cm] (Rh) at (2,0) {$R_{h}$};

  % Arrows
  \draw[->, thick] (Sr) -- (Ir);
  \draw[->, thick] (Sh) -- (Eh);
  \draw[->, thick] (Eh) -- (Ih);
  \draw[->, thick] (Ih) -- (Rh);
  \draw[->, thick] (Rh) -- (Sh);

  % Dotted Lines
  \draw[dotted, thick] (Sr) -- (Ih);
  \draw[dotted, thick] (Ir) -- (Sh);

  % Labels
  \node[anchor=south] at (-2,4) {Rodents};
  \node[anchor=south] at (-2,2) {Humans};
  \draw [<-] (Sh) -- ++(180:1.5cm) node[midway, above] {$\pi_{h}$};
  \draw [<-] (Sr) -- ++(180:1.5cm) node[midway, above] {$\pi_{r}$};
  \draw [->] (Eh) -- ++(260:1cm) node[midway, left] {$\mu_{h}$};
  \draw [->] (Sh) -- ++(350:1.5cm) node[midway, left] {$\mu_{h}$};
  \draw [->] (Ir) -- ++(290:1.1cm) node[midway, left] {$\mu_{r}$};
  \draw [->] (Ih) -- ++(240:1.2cm) node[midway, left] {$\mu_{h}+\delta_{h}$};
  \draw [->] (Sr) -- ++(280:1.2cm) node[midway, left] {$\mu_{r}$};
  \draw [->] (Rh) -- ++(80:1.2cm) node[midway, left] {$\mu_{h}$};
  \end{tikzpicture}

  \end{document}


Purely for comparison, here is an effort in Metapost, the drawing language built into LuaLaTex.

Here is the source.  You need to compile this with lualatex.
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{luamplib}
\begin{document}
\mplibtextextlabel{enable}
\begin{mplibcode}
beginfig(1);

  numeric u; u = 28;
  % lay out some points using the z$ = (x$, y$) notation
  y0 = y1 = y2 = 0;
  y3 = -3.5u; y4 = y5 = 4u;
  x0 = x3 = 0; -x1 = x2 = 5u; -x4 = x5 = 4u;

  % define the shapes
  path hexagon, Sr, Ir, Sh, Eh, Ih, Rh;
  hexagon = (for i=0 upto 5: 24 dir 60i -- endfor cycle) yscaled 3/4;
  Sr = hexagon shifted z4;
  Ir = hexagon shifted z5;
  Sh = hexagon shifted z1;
  Eh = hexagon shifted z0;
  Ih = hexagon shifted z2;
  Rh = hexagon shifted z3;

  % draw dashed crossed lines first (so they are underneath the edges of the hexagons
  draw point 5 of Sr -- point 2 of Ih dashed evenly scaled 1/2 withcolor 1/3[red, blue];
  draw point 1 of Sh -- point 4 of Ir dashed evenly scaled 1/2 withcolor 1/3[red, blue];

  % draw and decorate all the of the shapes using a one-off macro
  vardef decorate(suffix p)(expr shade) = 
    fill p withcolor 7/8[shade, white];
    draw p;
    label("$" & substring (0,1) of str p & "_" & substring (1,2) of str p & "$", center p);
  enddef;

  forsuffixes $=Sr, Ir: decorate($, red); endfor
  forsuffixes $=Sh, Ih, Eh, Rh: decorate($, blue); endfor

  % make arrows narrow
  ahangle := 30;

  % mark the inputs
  vardef do_input(suffix p)(expr t, shade) = 
    save z; pair z; z = point 3 of p shifted (-u, 0);
    label.lft(t, z); drawarrow z -- point 3 of p withcolor shade;
  enddef;

  do_input(Sr, "$\pi_r$", 1/2 red);
  do_input(Sh, "$\pi_h$", 1/2 blue);

  % mark the outputs
  vardef do_output(suffix p)(expr n, t, shade) = 
    save z, a;
    numeric a; a = abs(point n of p - center p);
    pair z; z = (1+u/a)[center p, point n of p];
    label(t, z); drawarrow point n of p -- z cutafter fullcircle scaled 12 shifted z withcolor shade;
  enddef;

  do_output(Sr, 4, "$\mu_r$", 1/2 red);
  do_output(Ir, 5, "$\mu_r$", 1/2 red);
  
  do_output(Sh, 5, "$\mu_h$", 1/2 blue);
  do_output(Eh, 5, "$\mu_h$", 1/2 blue);
  do_output(Ih, 5, "$\mu_h+\delta_h$", 1/2 blue);
  do_output(Rh, 5, "$\mu_h$", 1/2 blue);

  % define the rest of the connectors, then draw and label them
  path a[];
  a1 = point 0 of Sr -- point 3 of Ir; 

  drawarrow a1 withcolor 1/2 red;
  label.top("$\lambda_r$", point 1/2 of a1);

  a2 = point 0 of Sh -- point 3 of Eh;
  a3 = point 0 of Eh -- point 3 of Ih;
  a4 = point 4.5 of Ih -- (x2, y3) -- point 0 of Rh;
  a5 = point 3 of Rh -- (x1, y3) -- point 4.5 of Sh;

  for i=2 upto 5:
    drawarrow a[i] withcolor 1/2 blue;
  endfor

  label.top("$\lambda_h$", point 1/2 of a2);
  label.top("$\sigma_h$",  point 1/2 of a3);
  label.top("$\tau_h$",    point 3/2 of a4);
  label.top("$\xi_h$",     point 1/2 of a5);

  % finally add the two white on black labels
  picture T[];
  T1 = thelabel("\textsf{Rodents}", point 2 of Sr shifted (-u, 1/2 u));
  T2 = thelabel("\textsf{Humans}",  point 2 of Sh shifted (-u, 1/2 u));
  fill bbox T1; draw T1 withcolor white;
  fill bbox T2; draw T2 withcolor white;

endfig;
\end{mplibcode}
\end{document}

Follow the first link at the top for tutorials and reference material for Metapost.

Does it require LuaTeX because it includes stuff only available there? Or only for the compilation in situ? Most of it looks familiar, but not all and I'm far from knowledgeable about mp.

If you use the standalone class, as my example shows, then lualatex will produce a "standalone" PDF that contains all the resources it needs, and that has a bounding box sized to the contents of the drawing.  You can then include this directly, like any other graphic, in a pdflatex document using \includegraphics.

@cfr the key difference between plain MP and this luamplib example is the magic \mplibtextextlabel{enable} option.  This means that <string> arguments to the label macro are automatically passed through the TEX() macro, which simplifies things a bit.

Ah, yes. OK. That makes sense. I think I used textpath but it takes two runs for the text to show up correctly. Thanks. (It is a long time since I did this. Once I discovered tikz, I mostly abandoned metapost.)

Here's one way to do it. I leave it somewhat unfinished, as it's quite tedious for me, to figure out which line color shall go where. But you get the idea. Main points:
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
        plg/.style={draw, regular polygon, regular polygon sides=6, minimum size=1cm},
        or/.style={fill=orange!30},
        bl/.style={fill=blue!10!teal!20},
        CR/.style={black!50!red!100},
        CP/.style={purple},
        >={Stealth}, % just a proposal


introduce a number of styles/formats
the first abstracts your polygon parameters
this both cleans up code AND allows you to "change in one place only"
the colors: here I used the Tikz mixing modell to mix one or two colors
you can use other color models, too
have a look at library arrows.meta, where you may find nicer arrow tips
you may want to consider combining both line width and color in on style

RESULT:

CODE:
    \documentclass{article}
    \usepackage{tikz}
    \usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric, arrows, calc}
    \usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta} % just a proposal

    \begin{document}

    \begin{tikzpicture}[
        plg/.style={draw, regular polygon, regular polygon sides=6, minimum size=1cm},
        or/.style={fill=orange!30},
        bl/.style={fill=blue!10!teal!20},
        CR/.style={black!50!red!100},
        CP/.style={purple},
        >={Stealth}, % just a proposal
    ]
    % Nodes
    % Rodents
   \node[plg,or] (Sr) at (0,4) {$S_{r}$};
   \node[plg,or] (Ir) at (4,4) {$I_{r}$};
   % Humans
   \node[plg,bl] (Sh) at (0,2) {$S_{h}$};
   \node[plg,bl] (Eh) at (2,2) {$E_{h}$};
   \node[plg,bl] (Ih) at (4,2) {$I_{h}$};
   \node[plg,bl] (Rh) at (2,0) {$R_{h}$};

  % Arrows
  \draw[->, thick,CR] (Sr) -- (Ir);
  \draw[->, thick] (Sh) -- (Eh);
  \draw[->, thick] (Eh) -- (Ih);
  \draw[->, thick] (Ih) -- (Rh);
  \draw[->, thick] (Rh) -- (Sh);

  % Dotted Lines
  \draw[dotted, thick,CP] (Sr) -- (Ih);
  \draw[dotted, thick,CP] (Ir) -- (Sh);

  % Labels
  \node[anchor=south] at (-2,4) {Rodents};
  \node[anchor=south] at (-2,2) {Humans};
  \draw [<-,CR] (Sr) -- ++(180:1.5cm) node[midway, above] {$\pi_{r}$};
  \draw [->,CR] (Ir) -- ++(290:1.1cm) node[midway, left] {$\mu_{r}$};
  
  \draw [<-] (Sh) -- ++(180:1.5cm) node[midway, above] {$\pi_{h}$};
  \draw [->] (Eh) -- ++(260:1cm)   node[midway, left] {$\mu_{h}$};
  \draw [->] (Sh) -- ++(350:1.5cm) node[midway, left] {$\mu_{h}$};
  \draw [->] (Ih) -- ++(240:1.2cm) node[midway, left] {$\mu_{h}+\delta_{h}$};
  \draw [->] (Sr) -- ++(280:1.2cm) node[midway, left] {$\mu_{r}$};
  \draw [->] (Rh) -- ++(80:1.2cm)  node[midway, left] {$\mu_{h}$};
  \end{tikzpicture}

  \end{document}


still apart from color, the picture is not same as given one, many arrow entries are missing and whole diagram is somehow small and congested

@MaryamZaman Questions should generally focus on particular issues e.g. how to add space or how to add colour or how to adjust directions of arrows or whatever. You're trying to ask about many different aspects of tikz, which is enormous, in a single question. Please do also have a look at the tutorial at the start of the manual for help with some of this.

As far as I can count, you alread put all lines and arrows, didn't you? // Look for matrix in the tutorial part of https://tikz.dev/ , which allows you to put all nodes more like in a table (i.e. on a kind of design grid).  // As a general strategy, separating your drawing from the main document gives you much more flexibility; see here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/701698/245790 .

I'm a beginner in coding, i could'nt understand much about the things u refer

Have a look into the tutorial parts of https://tikz.dev/ .  Unless you didn't write all this code yourself, many things should look familiar to you. If you are in a hurry, slow down and spend a few hours on scanning said tutorials.

This is a modification of MS-SPO's answer, but note that you should not expect to get answers which do multiple complicated things and should also look at the tutorial section of the PGF/TikZ manual, which is much more accessible than the denser reference section.
This answer focuses on a strategy to improve the positioning of elements. Adding additional elements should be straightforward, given you wrote the code in your question.
I do three things:

Set x=1.5cm, and y=1.5cm for the diagram to space things out a bit. This gives you more room to place additional elements.
Use the |- syntax to draw the arrows between Ih, Rh and Sh. This looks neater and reduces congestion further.
Adopt standard angles and lengths for the arrows, positioning the labels at the ends by anchor. I use symmetrical positioning options: an arrow drawn at -120 with a label anchored at 60, an arrow drawn at -60 with a label drawn at 120, an arrow drawn at 60 with label at -120 and an arrow at 120 with label at -60. These are chosen due to the shapes being hexagons.

This should give you space to add further elements using the techniques you're already using.
\documentclass{standalone}
% mod from MS-SPO's answer: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/719713/ and Maryam Zaman's question: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/719707/
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric, arrows, calc}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[
  plg/.style={draw, regular polygon, regular polygon sides=6, minimum size=1cm},
  or/.style={fill=orange!30},
  bl/.style={fill=blue!10!teal!20},
  CR/.style={black!50!red!100},
  CP/.style={purple},
  >={Stealth}, % just a proposal
  x=1.5cm,
  y=1.5cm,
  ]
  % Nodes
  % Rodents
  \node[plg,or] (Sr) at (0,4) {$S_{r}$};
  \node[plg,or] (Ir) at (4,4) {$I_{r}$};
  % Humans
  \node[plg,bl] (Sh) at (0,2) {$S_{h}$};
  \node[plg,bl] (Eh) at (2,2) {$E_{h}$};
  \node[plg,bl] (Ih) at (4,2) {$I_{h}$};
  \node[plg,bl] (Rh) at (2,0) {$R_{h}$};
  
  % Arrows
  \draw[->, thick,CR] (Sr) -- (Ir);
  \draw[->, thick] (Sh) -- (Eh);
  \draw[->, thick] (Eh) -- (Ih);
  \draw[->, thick] (Ih) |- (Rh);
  \draw[->, thick] (Rh) -| (Sh);
  
  % Dotted Lines
  \draw[dotted, thick,CP] (Sr) -- (Ih);
  \draw[dotted, thick,CP] (Ir) -- (Sh);
  
  % Labels
  \node[anchor=south] at (-2,4) {Rodents};
  \node[anchor=south] at (-2,2) {Humans};
  \draw [<-,CR] (Sr) -- ++(180:1.5cm) node[midway, above] {$\pi_{r}$};
  \draw [->,CR] (Ir) -- ++(-60:1.2cm) node[anchor=120] {$\mu_{r}$};
  
  \draw [<-] (Sh) -- ++(180:1.5cm) node[midway, above] {$\pi_{h}$};
  \draw [->] (Eh) -- ++(-120:1.2cm)   node[anchor=60] {$\mu_{h}$};
  \draw [->] (Sh) -- ++(-60:1.2cm) node[anchor=120] {$\mu_{h}$};
  \draw [->] (Ih) -- ++(-120:1.2cm) node[anchor=60] {$\mu_{h}+\delta_{h}$};
  \draw [->] (Sr) -- ++(-120:1.2cm) node[anchor=60] {$\mu_{r}$};
  \draw [->] (Rh) -- ++(60:1.2cm)  node[anchor=120] {$\mu_{h}$};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}


