Create environment for figures
I would like to create an environment to add figures with the following requirements:

Top and bottom horizontal lines with the same width of the figure
Title at top of figure, source and legend at bottom; left and right margins match the figure width

I have the following MWE:
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper]{memoir}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[
    format          = hang,         %... alinha a legenda após seu título
    labelsep        = endash,       %... traço após identificação
    justification   = justified,    %... legenda justificada
    singlelinecheck = false,        %... justifica legenda de uma linha
    ]{caption}

\newcommand{\figTitle}[1]{\caption{#1}}
\newcommand{\figSource}[1]{\caption*{\small Source: #1}}
\newcommand{\figLegend}[1]{\caption*{\small #1}}


\begin{document}

\chapter{Test chapter}

This how I would add a figure to my text:

\begin{figure}[hbt]
    \centering
    \captionsetup{width=10cm}
    \figTitle{A CD and an scanning electron microscopy image}
    \rule{10cm}{0.5pt} \\
    \includegraphics[width=10cm]{CD.pdf} \\ \vspace{-4mm}
    \rule{10cm}{0.5pt} \\
    \figSource{Wikipedia}
    \figLegend{A CD is made up of microscopic grooves that are approximately parallel in a very small scale. The length at the bottom right represents $1~\mu$m.}
    \label{CD and SEM}
\end{figure}

\end{document}

It is cumbersome to repeat the same values many times, such as that for captionsetup and includegraphics widths that is the same for themselves and for the rule as well.
Is there a way to simplify this job? I mean: is there a way to create a new environment that works just like that of figure? Thank you!

Did you look for \newenvironment or \NewDocumentEnvironment?

I think a macro is sufficient here: after all, what would be the essential content in the environment? The one and only image? Etc.
Same considerations as here.
I assumed you want the rules on top and on bottom, because you'd only see that tiny partial frame with light images.
CD.png:

Here my memory faded: \includegraphics reads both bitmap and .pdf formats.

If you want to include a .pdf as image, use \includepdf from
graphicx instead.



\documentclass[12pt, a4paper]{memoir}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[
    format          = hang,         %... alinha a legenda após seu título
    labelsep        = endash,       %... traço após identificação
    justification   = justified,    %... legenda justificada
    singlelinecheck = false,        %... justifica legenda de uma linha
    ]{caption}

\newcommand{\figTitle}[1]{\caption{#1}}
\newcommand{\figSource}[1]{\caption*{\small Source: #1}}
\newcommand{\figLegend}[1]{\caption*{\small #1}}

\newcommand\figinsert[6]{%
% 1: width, 2: title, 3: file, 4: source, 5: legend, 6: label
\begin{figure}[hbt]%
    \centering%
    \captionsetup{width=#1}%
    \rule{#1}{.5pt}\\%
    \figTitle{#2}%
    \includegraphics[width=#1]{#3}\\ \vspace{-4mm}%
    \figSource{#4}%
    \figLegend{#5}%
    \label{#6}%
    \rule{#1}{.5pt}\\%
\end{figure}}
% ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
\begin{document}

\chapter{Test chapter}

This how I would add a figure to my text:

\figinsert  {10cm}
            {A CD and an scanning electron microscopy image}
            {CD.png}
            {Wikipedia}
            {A CD is made up of microscopic grooves that are approximately parallel in a very small scale. The length at the bottom right represents $1~\mu$m.}
            {CD and SEM}


\figinsert{5cm}{Some nonsense}{example-image-a}{No content at all}{No source}{nons}

You will be amazed about figure \ref{nons} \dots

\end{document}


graphicx doesn't provide \includepdf and \includepdf always starts a new page. it's from the pdfpages package. I'm not sure what you had in mind as an alternative to \includegraphics?

Right, wrong recall: includegraphics can also process .pdf. See e.g. here, 2nd file: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/701698/245790

perhaps you could correct your answer? :-)

You could define a macro called, say, \myfig, that takes six arguments.
Some observations, not ordered by priority:

I wouldn't write $1~\mu$m. Instead, I'd load the siunitx package and use its \qty macro as follows: \qty{1}{\micro\meter}. Note that the glyphs produced by $\mu$ and \micro are not the same.

I would also streamline the definitions of \figSource and \figLegend.

Do note that there's no gap between the horizontal lines drawn by \hrule and the image. That way, if the image is already framed with black lines, the additional horizontal lines won't show up in a distracting way.



\documentclass[12pt, a4paper]{memoir}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[
    format          = hang,      %... alinha a legenda após seu título
    labelsep        = endash,    %... traço após identificação
    justification   = justified, %... legenda justificada
    singlelinecheck = false,     %... justifica legenda de uma linha
    skip=0.333\baselineskip,
    ]{caption}

\newcommand{\figTitle}[1]{\caption{#1}}
\newcommand{\figSource}[1]{\smallskip{\small Source: #1\par}}
\newcommand{\figLegend}[1]{\medskip{\small #1\par}}

\newcommand\myfig[6]{%
   \begin{figure}[htb]
   \centering
   \begin{minipage}{#1} % desired width
   \figTitle{#2}        % caption
   \hrule
   \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{#3} % name of image file
   \hrule
   \figSource{#4} % source attribution
   \figLegend{#5} % legend
   \label{#6}     % label (for cross-referencing)
   \end{minipage}
   \end{figure}%
   }

\usepackage{siunitx} % for \qty macro

\begin{document}

\chapter{Test chapter}

This how I would add a figure to my text:
\myfig{10cm}
    {A CD and an scanning electron microscopy image}
    {example-image-a}
    {Wikipedia}
    {A CD is made up of microscopic grooves that are approximately parallel in a very small scale. The length at the bottom right represents \qty{1}{\micro\meter}.}
    {CD and SEM}
  
\end{document}


I will weigh in with a vote to use the powers in NewDocumentCommand rather than newcommand. I am never a fan of setting absolute lengths versus using relative distances to the (printed) text content, but this is an easy enough change in the specifics of the command. I also changed in the order of input parameters, putting the file name first, followed by the "meta data" that describes what is being put in place. Finally, I'd name the command centerFigure to accent that it puts the figure in the center (e.g. as opposed to just "putting" the figure).
The tweaking to include extra spacings at certain locations is entirely up to the aesthetics of the user and can be easily incorporated as desired.
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper]{memoir}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[
    format          = hang,         %... alinha a legenda após seu título
    labelsep        = endash,       %... traço após identificação
    justification   = justified,    %... legenda justificada
    singlelinecheck = false,        %... justifica legenda de uma linha
    ]{caption}

\newcommand{\figText}[2][]{\caption*{\small #1 #2}}

%% centerFigure[textwidth multiplier (1),line thickness (0.5pt)]
            {file}{title}{source}{legend}{label}
\NewDocumentCommand\centerFigure{O{1} O{0.5pt} m m m +m m}{%
    \begin{figure}[htb]
    \centering
    \captionsetup{width=#1\textwidth}
    \rule{#1\textwidth}{#2}
    \caption{#4}
    \includegraphics[width=#1\textwidth]{#3}
    \figText[Source:]{#5}
    \figText{#6}
    \label{#7}
    \rule{#1\textwidth}{#2}
    \end{figure}
    }

\begin{document}

\chapter{Test chapter}

This how I would add centered figures to text.

\centerFigure{fig-CD}
    {The Figure Title}
    {A Reference Source}
    {Some legend text. This can extent over paragraphs (whereas the others cannot), as demonstrated by writing a long sentence.}
    {fig:CDfull}

\centerFigure[0.5]{fig-CD}
    {The Figure Title}
    {A Reference Source}
    {The same figure as before but at half the text width.}
    {fig:CDhalf}

\centerFigure[][3pt]{fig-CD}
    {The Figure Title}
    {A Reference Source}
    {The same figure as the first but with thicker border lines.}
    {fig:CDhalfandthicker}

\end{document}

With adjustments using O versus m inputs for the source input and the use of IfBlankTF or IfNoValueTF directives, one could likely also make the command flexible to handle figures that should have no sources (rather than writing an entirely new command just for those too).
