How to encode a flow chart where at each arrow there is multi-line text and the next block automatically adjusts it's position?
I'm currently trying to encode a flow chart of algebraic structures. I want the object name in the box and the additional mathematical structure besides the arrow (like in the picture below). Eventually the chart will be more complex with arrows from the blue chart to the red chart (when defining modules), a single text for multiple arrows (e.g. Ring and Commutative ring will have an arrow to Skew Field and Field resp. by the same structural operation) etc. The text I'm making a flow chart from is found here (section A.1).
Currently, I have the code (at the end of my question) that produces the flow chart in the picture. This is the desired output. Though, as the code reveals, the positioning of 'set R', 'monoid' and 'group' is hard coded by using xshift and yshift. I suspect this will bring headache when the chart is made more complex.
My question is: is this the best way to display the flow chart? And if so, is there a better way to make my flow chart so that the position of 'monoid' is vertically aligned below 'set M' but automatically positioned to account for the space of the text?

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

\begin{document}

\tikzstyle{block_set} = [rectangle, rounded corners, minimum width=3cm, minimum height=1cm,text centered, draw=black, fill=red!30]
\tikzstyle{block_ring} = [rectangle, rounded corners, minimum width=3cm, minimum height=1cm,text centered, draw=black, fill=blue!30]
\tikzstyle{arrow} = [thick,->,>=stealth]
\newcommand{\blocktext}[2]{
\node[below right=0 cm and -1.5cm of #1, align=left, text width=6cm] (text_#1) {#2};
}

\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=2cm]

\node (set_M) [block_set] {Set $M$};
\blocktext{set_M}{Binary Composition (BC) $*$\\ $*$ is associative};

\node (monoid) [block_set, below of=set_M, yshift=-0.5cm] {Monoid};
\blocktext{monoid}{$\exists$ a unit $e$\\ $\exists$ an inverse $\forall x\in M$}

\node (Group) [block_set, below of=monoid, yshift=-0.5cm] {Group};

\node (set_R) [block_ring, right of=set_M, xshift=6cm] {Set $R$};

\draw [arrow] (set_M) -- (monoid);
\draw [arrow] (monoid) -- (Group);

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}


Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with \documentclass{...}, the required \usepackage's, \begin{document}, and \end{document}. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for the users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

I believe the code is now compilable, thanks for the heads up. Not tedious at all, I'm happy to help someone else help.

Look for matrix in the Tikz manual, which may be useful for many flowcharts. // For a kind of automation you could use anchors. E.g. \nodeanchor=north west at (M.south) {math things}; and next place the north anchor of the Monoid e.g. 1cm below (T1.south east) . Place other content relative to to useful nodes. Use xshift or yshift. // Use the standalone class for each chart. See e.g. here for this approach https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/701698/245790

I suggest these modifications:

don't use \tikzstyle, that's deprecated

instead of moving the nodes around with xshift and yshift, you could use the positioning library to position them at a given distance from other nodes. In case you need more space for the annotations, you'll only need to modify this one length and everything else will move accordingly.

instead of drawing the arrows and annotations separately, you could add the text midway of the arrows:



\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

\begin{document}

\tikzset{
  block_set/.style={rectangle, rounded corners, minimum width=3cm, minimum height=1cm,text centered, draw=black, fill=red!30},
  block_ring/.style={rectangle, rounded corners, minimum width=3cm, minimum height=1cm,text centered, draw=black, fill=blue!30},
  arrow/.style={thick,->,>=stealth},
  mytext/.style={align=left, text width=6cm,midway,right}
}

\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=2cm]

\node (set_M) [block_set] {Set $M$};
\node (monoid) [block_set, below=1.5cm of set_M] {Monoid};
\node (Group) [block_set, below=1.5cm of monoid] {Group};
\node (set_R) [block_ring, right=6cm of set_M] {Set $R$};

\draw [arrow] (set_M) -- (monoid) node[mytext] {Binary Composition (BC) $*$\\ $*$ is associative};
\draw [arrow] (monoid) -- (Group) node[mytext] {$\exists$ a unit $e$\\ $\exists$ an inverse $\forall x\in M$};

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}



With the chains library
Code
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{chains}

\begin{document}

\noindent\begin{tikzpicture}[
    node distance = 1.5cm and 6cm,
    start chain = B  going below,
    arrow/.style={
        thick,
        -stealth,
    },
    B/.style = {
        on chain=B,
        rounded corners,
        minimum width=3cm, 
        minimum height=1cm,
        text centered, 
        draw=black, 
        fill=#1!30,
        },
]
    \node [B=red] {Set $M$}; % B-1
    \node [B=red] {Monoid};  % B-2
    \node [B=red] {Group};   % B-3
    %
    \node [B=blue,right= of B-1] {Set $R$}; % B-4
    %
    \draw[arrow](B-1)--node[right, align=left]{Binary Composition (BC) $*$\\ $*$ is associative}(B-2);
    \draw[arrow](B-2)--node[right, align=left]{$\exists$ a unit $e$\\ $\exists$ an inverse $\forall x\in M$}(B-3);
    %
    \draw[arrow,dashed](B-2.east)to [out=0,in=200](B-4);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}



I made the following changes compared to your original code:

Added the calc library: I included the \usetikzlibrary{calc} to enable coordinate calculation, which is necessary for positioning the text relative to the arrows.

Positioned text relative to the arrows: I used $(m-1-1)!0.5!(m-2-1)$ to calculate the midpoint between the nodes at m-1-1 and m-2-1, and placed the text just to the right of that midpoint (using right=0.1cm). The same method was used for the second arrow.


This therefore gives :
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning, matrix, calc}

\begin{document}

\tikzstyle{block_set} = [rectangle, rounded corners, minimum width=3cm, minimum height=1cm, text centered, draw=black, fill=red!30]
\tikzstyle{block_ring} = [rectangle, rounded corners, minimum width=3cm, minimum height=1cm, text centered, draw=black, fill=blue!30]
\tikzstyle{arrow} = [thick,->,>=stealth]

\begin{tikzpicture}[
  node distance=2cm,
  every matrix/.style={column sep=2cm, row sep=1.5cm},
  every node/.style={align=center}
]

% Define the matrix
\matrix (m) [matrix of nodes, nodes={draw, rounded corners, minimum width=3cm, minimum height=1cm, text centered}, column sep=3cm, row sep=1.5cm] {
  |[block_set]| Set $M$ & |[block_ring]| Set $R$ \\
  |[block_set]| Monoid & \\
  |[block_set]| Group  & \\
};

% Add annotations directly to the right of the arrows
\node[align=left, text width=6cm, right=0.1cm of $(m-1-1)!0.5!(m-2-1)$] {Binary Composition (BC) $*$\\ $*$ is associative};
\node[align=left, text width=6cm, right=0.1cm of $(m-2-1)!0.5!(m-3-1)$] {$\exists$ a unit $e$\\ $\exists$ an inverse $\forall x \in M$};

% Add arrows
\draw[arrow] (m-1-1) -- (m-2-1);
\draw[arrow] (m-2-1) -- (m-3-1);

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}


